# why is the javascript passing empty values into the php?

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following JS code to try and run a php script that performs an SQL statement to add to add data to a database.

```
function insertData(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("addName");
    var description = document.getElementById("addDescription");
    var price = document.getElementById("addPrice");
    console.log("NAME= ", name.value, "DES= ", description.value, "PRICE= ", price.value);
    if(name.value !="" && description.value !="" && price.value !=""){
        var url = "insertForm.php?Name=" + name.value + "&description=" + description.value + "&Price=" + price.value;
        xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
    else{
        alert("please enter some data");
    }
}

submitButton = document.getElementById("addButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", insertData);
```

When i click on the submit button on the page the script runs and there are no error messages on the console. However when I load the database empty values are displayed and have been added in the database. I used the `console.log` to see if it was taking the values and the values are output correctly. I have believe the problem is with the url but i do not understand why it is passing empty values to the php script and running the script with empty values. I have the other code available if needed I can post it.

The form i am using are as follows...

```
<body>
<section id="formSection">
  <form id="dataForm" method="post">
  <div>
    <h1>Add Product:</h1>
    <lable >Product Name:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addName" type="text" name="Name">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Description:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addDescription" type="text" name="description">
  </div>
  <div>
    <lable>Price:</lable>
    <input class="inputForm" id="addPrice" type="text" name="Price">
  </div>
  <div id="theSubmit">
    <button id="addButton">Submit</button>
  </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: You are sending a `POST` request, but using `GET` variables. That might have something to do with it.

Comment: It looks to me like you are passing the values in $_GET and you expect them to show up in $_POST. Try using $_REQUEST on the server side so you can check both. If that works, then is probably is a mixup between get and post.

Comment: I can see several different things that *might* be wrong (data in wrong place, data not being escaped, form being submitted, etc). Look at your browser's developer tools. Look at the HTTP request. Is it being sent? Does it get the response you expect? Look at your PHP. How are you trying to read the values?

Comment: hi guys in my form tags i am using ` POST ` i will post the forms for you incase this helps

Comment: @Tom — That doesn't matter. You aren't (presumably) actually submitting the form.

Comment: The form html isnt' very important We need to see the php

Comment: Use a [validator](http://validator.w3.org) — you have some obvious errors (which probably aren't the cause of your problem, but you need to do the debugging I recommended in my previous comment).

Comment: okay @Quentin thanks, i'm new to javascript so every pointer helps :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To POST data like an HTML form with xmlhttp.send(), and not GET data you need to structure it like the following.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","insertForm.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&description=" + description.value + "&Price=" + price.value);
```

That will at least POST your data. You have many other errors though.

Comment: this worked, however, i do fully understand what the `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader` does, can you please explain?

Comment: This tells the server whats being sent to it. So it's saying the content-type is Form encoded data. The MIME Type.  Check out this list http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type

Comment: Another side note is your first example was correct, but just for a GET request.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use jQuery and its function $.post()

```
$.post("test.php", { 'name': name.value, 'description': description.value, 'price': price.value });
```

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Here you can define data in an array which you can access with $_POST['name'], $_POST['description'] and $_POST['price'] in the php script.
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php

Comment: *"Here you can define data in an **object**"*

Comment: okay I will have a look into this to understand it and try this

Comment: The only thing I'm not quite sure of is whether or not you need the two **' '** in the object itself, just try it. :)